# CSS - Detecting if user changed browsers default font

Tags: css, user-interface, accessibility, user-experience, font-family

Is there a way to detect, in pure CSS (no Javascript) if a user has *changed* the default font of the browser?

This a web accessibility related question, where the idea is to respect the user's preferred font. For font-size this works by using relative font sizes (such as %). But for the font-family I would like to define the site's font eg:

```
body {
 font-family: Verdana, sans-serif, serif;
}
```

With the above CSS I know sans-serif and serif default to whatever is set in the browser. However generally most users will have Verdana so the font will be Verdana. However, if a users has changed their browsers font, I would like to respect that - but only if they changed it. Those who didn't change it, probably don't care. So I would like to do something like:

```
body {
 font-family: preferred-user-font, Verdana, sans-serif, serif;
}
```

Or maybe with some sort of media query, like: "@preferred-font"?

But I can't find anything for achieving this - the key part being detecting a changed browser default font.

Comment: Maybe you can use something like [CSS Variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties), but really, CSS is loaded on a "per page load" routine so this would only notice if the default font was changed *during the display of the page* .

Comment: Define the time frame for "changed"; is it changed while the page is open, while the website is open, that month, that week, during any cookies exist from that website, or ever?

Comment: @Martin: I mean changed in the browser settings.

Comment: It would be a bad browser update if it changed a user's previous setting. If it simply updated the browser default (eg from Times New Roman to Arial) that wouldn't count as a change. I would like to  know if there is a way to detect if the user has picked a preferred font (eg a font which is maybe dyslexic friendly)

Comment: If you don't set a font, the default browser font will be applied. However if your site uses different languages, you risk the special characters not to be there.

Comment: Very few users change the default font, plus they are used to see oredefined fonts on other websites. It's not worth it taking this into consideration. Just set a good font and everybody will be happy.

Comment: Not possible in CSS I am afraid. Could be done with some JS and a bit of a hack using an unstyled element and `element.style.font` though I think, but I have never tried it.

Comment: @azu is there a reference for this?

Comment: This is an interesting q and might be important to some users. Is there a reason for not allowing JS therefore?

Comment: A reference to what?

Comment: By the way, changing the default font of the browser is related to the browser application, not to the webpage. So you cannot detect it by CSS or by JS.

Comment: @AHaworth the reason for not wanting JS is that I don't feel this should need JS. It's a styling this. I am actually not expecting this to be possible, but I am asking in case I missed something in CSS specification.

Comment: @Azu the fact that it's a browser setting does not mean it can't be detected in CSS. You can detect (or at least infer) things like screen size using media queries. There is a query for the users theme preference (dark/light). But there seems to be no way for a user to tell a website their preferred font.  Most people won't care about this, but for some users it's quite important and they should not need to rely on plugin to solve.

Comment: The things you mentioned are related to the loaded page, not to the beowser.

Comment: Surely the two go to together. The change is in the browser, but I want the website to respond to this.  If you change the default browser font-size (eg from the default medium to large) a well designed site will display larger font (and in fact the change in the site is immediate - but that is the browser re-drawing the page and is not my immediate concern).  I want to know if the user has changed the default browser font or not. It seems not to be possible.

Comment: I understand feeliing that CSS should be able to 'know' all browser settings, but it seems it can't so I think JS at run time is the only answer for now.